# Javascript and Flash in AS3

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to use Javascript in flash. For example, as a simple test I am trying to use Javascript's alert method when a button is clicked.

I am using AS3. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think so... you use actionscript in flash if I remember correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Marty mentioned, you can use the **ExternalInterface** class to execute a Javascript. Your options are to execute a function embedded in the (html) page code and create one from scratch. Because `alert` is a default function you can use its name as the first parameter for the `call` method (of `ExternalInterface`) and the string as the 2nd one.

If you provide a single parameter, you might wanna write a function instead to execute (or return) something.

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
function btnClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("alert","something");
    // or
    ExternalInterface.call("function(){alert('something');}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.. Flash uses ActionScript 3.

You can call a JavaScript function on the same page as an embedded SWF using ActionScript's [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class, though.

A quick demo on implementing [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html):

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
    ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Hello!");
```

Tip: [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) calls will not work locally unless you add the location of the project in [**this security settings panel**](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) and check "always allow".